# Django Rest Framework testing function that uses requests library

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework

How can I test the following function in a django project?

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_films(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        r = requests.get('https://swapi.co/api/films')
        if r.status_code == 200:
            data = r.json()
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"error": "Request failed"}, status=r.status_code)
    else:
        return Response({"error": "Method not allowed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mock requests.

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class YourTests(APITestCase):

    def test_get_films_success(self):
        with patch('*location of your get_films_file*.requests') as mock_requests:
            mock_requests.post.return_value = mock_response = Mock()
            mock_response.status_code = 200
            mock_response.json.return_value = {'message': "Your expected response"}
            response = self.client.get(f'{your_url_for_get_films_view}')
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
            self.assertEqual(response.data, {'message': f'{expected_response}'})
```

With the similar approach you can test all your conditions for wrong Method or 404 response.

Comment: Thanks . When you say '*location of your get_films_file*.requests' ... I have my functions in views.py . Also the 'your_url_for_get_films_view' ..do youmean the endpoint I have created for the view? For example /films or call the external api?

Comment: `location of get_films_file` Yes, I meant your view location like `yourapp.views.requests` because it's important to mock `requests` in file where it's being called from.
For url `your_url_for_get_films_view`, absolutely, endpoint where you send your get requests for triggering this view to work.

Comment: Sorry I haven't done this before : do you mean something like this : `response = self.client.get(f'{'api/films/'}')` cause I get a syntax error. 
My view url is this `url(r'films/$',views.get_films,name="get-films"),`

Comment: if you need to call `example.com/api/films/` for calling it, yes. You can have simply `self.client.get('api/films/') `

Comment: I get an assertionError 404!=200